# JavaScript or jQuery on click toggle button display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, squarespace

For an artist's Squarespace site, trying to display a button on the lightbox so users can send a direct message regarding a piece they like.

I can get the button to display when an image thumb is clicked, but can't seem to get the button to hide when the lightbox closes.

**I Initially tried it in Vanilla JS but had to go to jQuery  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` 
  [Check out on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/luukee/xpvt214o/741652/)

Displaying the contact button on `thumb-image` click:

```
$('.thumb-image').click(function () {
    var content = $("body").find('.form-block');
    content.addClass("toggle-content");
});
```

And my attempt to hide the button on lightbox close.

```
$('.featherlight-close').click(function () {
    var hideButton = $("body").find('.form-block');
    hideButton.addClass("toggle");
});
```

A breakdown of my thought process:

1. **Event**: click image thumb -> **Lightbox Visible**

   ```
   <img class="thumb-image loaded" src="...>
   ```

   - *lightbox is originally not present on the page, it is loaded by JavaScript directly below the opening* `body` *tag*.
2. **Contact Button Displays**

   ```
   <div class="form-block"></div>
   ```

   - *trying to display the contact button by jQuery's* `addClass` *method and this class*

     ```
     .toggle-content { display: block; }
     ```
3. **Event**: Close lightbox

   ```
   <a class="lightbox-close"></a>
   ```

   - *the close "X" is on a pseudo element, and I found this to really complicate things :|*

     ```
     lightbox-close:before
     ```
4. **Contact Button Hidden** - on click toggle class to hide button.

   ```
   .toggle { display: none}
   ```

**[Check out on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/luukee/xpvt214o/741652/)**

Your help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: very good point @Pete. thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove existing class and add new classes for toggle kind of functionalities

```
$('.thumb-image').click(function () {
    var content = $("body").find('.form-block');
    content.removeClass("toggle");
    content.addClass("toggle-content");
});

$('.featherlight-close').click(function () {
    var hideButton = $("body").find('.form-block');
    hideButton.removeClass("toggle-content");
    hideButton.addClass("toggle");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Pradeep PK. It makes sense to `removeClass` and `addClass`. Exactly what I was looking for. The only thing is, the `.featherlight-close` class click function will not work because of the click element being a `:before` pseudo class.

I implemented your code on the jsFiddle I created check it out:
https://jsfiddle.net/luukee/xpvt214o/750675/
and let me know how you would solve this because I cannot seem to find a workaround.

thanks again!

Comment: did you have a look at my jsFiddle? Thanks again, Luke